# Running Shinyapp in Docker without Shiny server

Tags: r, docker, shiny

I'm trying to run a Shiny app inside Docker and I see two ways to do it:

1) Run Shiny server in Docker and then run Shiny app on this server. It works but I'm still struggling to make user directory visible from the Shiny app (simple mounting with -v parameter didn't help).

2) Run Shiny directly on Docker using the command `R -e "shiny::runApp('/srv/shiny-server/')"`. In this case, it almost works but I'm getting this error:

```
shiny::runApp('/srv/shiny-server/', launch.browser = T)
Loading required package: shiny
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4637
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 844: /usr/bin/xdg-open: www-browser: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 844: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 844: /usr/bin/xdg-open: elinks: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 844: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 844: /usr/bin/xdg-open: lynx: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 844: /usr/bin/xdg-open: w3m: not found
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://127.0.0.1:4637'
```

I tried to install browser (adding `apt-get install -y firefox` to my Dockerfile) but it still doesn't work.

I wasn't able to find any tutorials/examples on how to run a Shiny app on Docker without Shiny Server. So I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your second approach the R process tries to open a browser *within* the docker container since it thinks it is used interactively. A simple way to change this is to use `Rscript -e ...` instead of `R -e ...`. Alternatively you can set the `launch.browser` argument to `FALSE`.

In addition, you should bind the shiny app to a fixed port on any IP address and publish that port to the host when starting the docker container. You can do this with arguments `port = 3838` and `host = "0.0.0.0"`.

Instead of specifying these things via arguments, you could also use R's options mechanism by adding

```
options(shiny.port = 3838, shiny.host = "0.0.0.0", shiny.launch.browser = FALSE)
```

to `Rprofile.site`.

Comment: Thank you! Adding port and host to the command worked and I can open the shiny app in browser now. However, still can't access any directories from the app. I use -v parameter when I run docker container but inside the app I can see empty home "/srv/shiny-server" folder. Do you have any suggestions how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: I tried this:
`docker run --rm -p 3838:3838 -v /Users/svetlana/Downloads/magic/shiny/MagicWeb/:/srv/shiny-server/ -v /Users/svetlana/Downloads/magic/data/:/srv/shiny-server/data/ three_test`

Comment: @kintany This looks correct at first sight, but I vaguely remember that docker on mac can be quite different from the linux environments I am used to. Does the same problem happen with standard containers?

Comment: Yes, it was not specific to Mac, but I fixed it, thank you :)